# Splunk - Can Fields be used as app identifier

Tags: logging, splunk, indexer

I have an Splunk system receiving logs from various applications and the logs are reported to different indexes for each application.
Its becoming difficult to maintain indexes, my client has requested to club all the indexes into one.

I am thinking of defining single index for all the application and use field (app_id) to identify the logs coming from different applications. Does this looks like a logical solution. Any thoughts on this are welcome please.

Answer (score 0):

If it works for your data then yes, use app_id.  Don't forget there's also the `source` and `sourcetype` fields present in every event.  Most sites use sourcetype to distinguish events by application.